# Why does a 20MB JSON Array creates a 2GB Table

Tags: json, oracle

in Oracle 19C DB i have a json with the following format

```
"rows":[[1, "sometext", "some other text", timestamp, ...],
[..],
...]
```

with 43 Items (most of them strings from 1 to 150 characters long) and 1.2 Mio Itemsets.
It is saved in a blob column (JSON_BLOB ~ 20 MB) of a table (JSON_BLOB_TABLE ) with the "is json" constraint.

When i create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_JSON_TABLE AS (
select j.*
from JSON_BLOB_TABLE d, 
     json_table ( 
        d.JSON_BLOB, '$' columns ( 
            nested path '$.rows[*]' columns ( 
                col1 NUMBER PATH '$[0]',
                col2 VARCHAR2(8) PATH '$[1]',
                ...
            )
        )
     ) j 
)
```

the size of this table by

```
SELECT BYTES/1024/1024 MB FROM USER_SEGMENTS WHERE SEGMENT_NAME = 'MY_JSON_TABLE';
```

is more than 2000 MB. How is that possible? The amount of rows in this table is still 1.2 Mio, no columns were added.
Am i missing an important table configuration here to save space?

Comment: 2 GB  in Json for 1,2 million records is not so much. You could use `compress` for the table

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned about that space. 2 gb is barely a rounding error in a data center..  Thumb drivers bigger than that cost less than lunch..  But as to the question, "why", you'd need to look at the storage parameters for the table in question.  There is always overhead in table storage - it's not just the data itself that takes space.  Look at things like 'PCTFREE, PCTUSED, and INITTRANS.  Before making changes to thes just to save a few measly MB, be sure you understand what they mean, why they are currently set the way they are, and the impact of changing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made *two significant errors* in your observation:

**First** you confuse the size of the data and the size of the table.

The latter is always *higher* due to overhead and *free space*

Here simple example - the table has 1000 rows with approx. 1000 bytes per row

```
create table tab as
select rownum id, lpad('x',999,'y') txt
from dual connect by level <= 1000;
```

But it *allocates* 2 MB

```
select BYTES/1024/1024 MB  from user_segments where segment_name = 'TAB';
        MB
----------
         2
```

But the *size of the data* in the table is *as expected* close to 1MB  (checking the table statistics)

```
select NUM_ROWS, AVG_ROW_LEN,
(NUM_ROWS * AVG_ROW_LEN) /1024/1024 MB
from user_tables where table_name = 'TAB';

  NUM_ROWS AVG_ROW_LEN         MB
---------- ----------- ----------
      1000        1004 ,957489014
```

The **second** problem which is more serious is your estimatimation of the JSON column size.

```
create table tab_json as
select 1 id,
JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT (id, txt RETURNING BLOB) ORDER BY id RETURNING BLOB)  js
from tab;

select BYTES/1024/1024 MB  from user_segments where segment_name = 'TAB_JSON';

        MB
----------
,0625
```

The table with JSON column (stored as BLOB) containing all the data of 1 MB is only 62 KB large! How is this possible!!

Very simple - the JSON is stored as `BLOB` i.e. **not in the table, but in LOB segment**. You must find the LOB segment in `USER_LOBS` and check it's size

```
select SEGMENT_NAME from user_lobs where table_name = 'TAB_JSON';

SEGMENT_NAME                                                                                                                    
------------------------- 
SYS_LOB0000073542C00002$$

select BYTES/1024/1024 MB  from user_segments where segment_name in (
select SEGMENT_NAME from user_lobs where table_name = 'TAB_JSON');
        MB
----------
    2,1875
```

Now if you compare the whole size of the JSON table (i.e. table segments + LOB segments) you see there is no *big surprise* but the results are comparable.